# How can I solve $\langle \sin(pt),\cos(pt)\rangle = \langle \cos(qt),\sin(qt)\rangle$

Tags: vectors

How can I solve this vector equality where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$? $\langle \sin(pt),\cos(pt)\rangle = \langle \cos(qt),\sin(qt)\rangle$ I am trying to figure out how many times in a period they intersect.

Comment: Proper notation is $$\langle \sin(pt),\cos(qt)\rangle = \langle \cos(pt),\sin(qt)\rangle.$$  You had $$<sin(p*t),cos(q*t)>=<cos(p*t),sin(q*t)>.$$  Lots of LaTeX manuals online will tell you things like this. $\qquad$

Answer (score -1):

**Solution is now edited to contain both versions of the question you've asked**

**Version 1: $⟨sin(pt),cos(qt)⟩=⟨cos(pt),sin(qt)⟩$**

You need the $x$ and $y$ components to be equal so you are solving the simultaneous equations:

$\sin(pt)=\cos(pt)$ and $\cos(qt)=\sin(qt)$

These become: $\tan(pt)=1$ and $\tan(qt)=1$

So $pt=\frac{pi}{4}+\pi n_1,n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ and $qt=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n_2,n_2\in\mathbb{N}$

So $t=\frac{pi+4\pi n_1}{4p}=\frac{pi+4\pi n_2}{4q}$

This will only have solutions for some values of $p$ and $q$. Cross multiplying and dividing by $\pi$ gives:

$q+4n_1=p+4n_2$

As $p$ and $q$ are integers this will have no solutions unless $p-q=4m,m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Version 2: $⟨sin(pt),cos(pt)⟩=⟨cos(qt),sin(qt)⟩$**

Here each vector represents a rotation by $pt$ and $qt$ respectively. As $p$ and $q$ are integers they will obviously be equal when $t=2\pi n,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. They will also be equal before then if $p$ and $q$ have a common factor. So the solution is:

If $p=q$ then $t\in\mathbb{R}$

If $p\neq q$ then $t=\frac{2\pi}{\gcd(p,q)}$

Comment: $\tan$ has period $\pi$, not $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I would get sin(pt)/cos(qt)=1 though...

Comment: @Ryles2014 I answered the original question you posted. You've since then changed it. See Michael Hardy's comment for the question I answered.

Comment: @Element118 Thats what I mean. The final answer of $p-q=4m$ was based on period of $\pi$ not on the incorrect $2\pi$.